# How to use a claim resolver in Persisted claims?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, claims, resolver

I would like to store the last login time in an extension field whenever user is logged in. I have created a technical profile like below and call it from an orchestration step. My problem is that it is not resolving the `{Context:DateTimeInUtc}`, instead it writes the word `{Context:DateTimeInUtc}` in to the attribute.

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Custom-TP-AAD-UpdateLastLoginDate-UsingObjectId">
     <Metadata>
      <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
      <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
     </Metadata>
     <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
     <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
     </InputClaims>
     <PersistedClaims>
      <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_LastLoginDate" PartnerClaimType="{Context:DateTimeInUtc}" />
     </PersistedClaims>
     <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it should it be `DefaultValue="{Context:CorrelationId}"` rather than `PartnerClaimType="{Context:DateTimeInUtc}"` ?

Comment: What if you add `<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>`?

Comment: I already tried with DefaultValue and it did not work, after that only i posted this question in SO.

Comment: I also tried <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item> but it did not resolve the claims.

Comment: Hi Chris - Any thought on making this work using claim transformation or may be using rest api technical profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to do it using claim transformation .
As per Microsoft claim resolver can not be used with Persisted claims as of now. They are working to enable this feature for more technical profile types.

Here is the detailed steps to do it.

Step 1 : First add two claims

```xml
    <ClaimType Id="extension_LastLoginDate">
        <DisplayName>last time user logged in</DisplayName>
        <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>last time user logged in</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="CurrentTime">
        <DisplayName>Current time</DisplayName>
        <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Current time</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
```

First one is extension attribute which is used to store the value in AD. Second one is a temporary variable to hold the current date time.

Step 2 : Add new claims transformation, this is needed to get current data time (utc) in `CurrentTime` claim

```xml
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetSystemDateTime" TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime">
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CurrentTime" TransformationClaimType="currentDateTime" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Step 3 : Define a technical profile to update the `extension_LastLoginDate` attribute

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Custom-TP-AAD-WriteLastLoginDateUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CurrentTime" PartnerClaimType="extension_LastLoginDate" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Steps 4 : Update existing technical profile `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId`. This is an important step where you are going to call claims transformation and add `CurrentTime` claim in claim bag. I have used `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` technical profile but it can be any other technical profile as long as it is ensured that claims transformation has been called and `CurrentTime` claim is added to claims bag.

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="CurrentTime" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetSystemDateTime" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Step 5 : Finally you can call `Custom-TP-AAD-WriteLastLoginDateUsingObjectId`technical profile from one of the `OrchestrationStep` in any user journey

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="WriteLastLogonTime" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Custom-TP-AAD-WriteLastLoginDateUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```